# Creating epidemiological histogram using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Here is some dummy data:

```
dummy <- data.frame(numbers = 1:5,
                    symptomdate  = as.Date(c("2012-08-30", "2012-08-30", "2012-08-31", "2012-09-01", "2012-09-01")),
                    reporteddate = as.Date(c("2012-09-02", "2012-09-03", "2012-09-05", "2012-09-07", "2012-09-08")),
                    dateofdeath   = as.Date(c("2012-09-10", NA, NA, NA, "2012-09-31")),
                    gender = c("Female", "Male", "Male","Female", "Male"),
                    position = c("Resident", "Staff", "Resident", "Staff", "Staff"), 
                    outbreakdate = as.Date(c("2012-08-31","2012-08-31","2012-08-31","2012-08-31","2012-08-31")))
```

There are 5 cases of disease here, each represent a row in the data frame. I want to create a histogram which labels the symptom date on the x axis, and the number of cases on the y axis. I also want a stacked bar chart, so that Staff cases appear in one colour and Resident cases appear in another colour.

This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure how to make the y axis a count (instead of using as.numeric, which isn't what I want)..

```
ggplot(dummy, aes(fill=position, y=as.numeric(symptomdate), x=symptomdate)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
```

I would also LOVE for a little marker to show up in the chart with a label that says 'Oubreak date' i.e. a little line that marks August 31st 2012: *edit, like this: [line above outbreak date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/md2Mq.png)

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's realted to a ggplot issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4205. It should work if you  set a width to your bar

```
ggplot(dummy, aes(x=symptomdate, fill=position)) + 
  geom_bar(width=.9)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you soooo much! While I have you, any idea how to solve the second issue of adding a little marker to show up in the chart with a label that says 'Oubreak date' i.e. a little line that marks August 31st 2012?